# programmatically changing content of UITableview Header/foot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a table view which loads another xib file and uses the content of that new xib file to display the header. In this new xib I have a UIImageView and a label. I want to be able to change the image and the label from view did load. I have linked up everything in interface builder properly. It just won't change the image or the text label.

### Header file

```
////h file///
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyProfile.h"

@interface MainMenu : UITableViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
    UIImageView *imageview;
    UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

-(UIView *)headerView;
-(IBAction)fn:(id)sender;

@end
```

### Partial .m file

```
///// partial .m file////
-(UIView *)headerView
{
    if(!headerView)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
    }

    return headerView;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
    return [self headerView];
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self headerView] bounds].size.height;
}

-(id) init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"The Table"];

    menuitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [menuitems addObject:@"item one"];
    [menuitems addObject:@"item two"];

    fieldnames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [fieldnames addObject:@"Date of Birth"];
    [fieldnames addObject:@"Nationality"];

    label.text = @"new label value will not be displayed!";
}
```

Why won't the text label update?

I have set the header view's xib file's owner to be the main menu and I have connected the label in header view.xib up to the IBOutlet.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to make a property for headerView and connect the view in IB to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply SVD but this did not work

Comment: If you print out (via NSLog) headerView, imageView and label, are they initialized or are they nil?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply

All are null: headerview (null), imageview (null), Label (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it. I don't know If this is the way that you are supposed to do it but it works.

If you stick

```
    label.text = @"new label value will not be displayed!";
```

in

```
   -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       return [self headerView];
   }
```

and then reload the xib inside viewdidload:

```
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
```

it works. Is this the way you are supposed to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to add header in table view:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,tableView.frame.size.width,21)] autorelease];
    UILabel *feelingDate;
    feelingDate = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    feelingDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    feelingDate.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    feelingDate.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    feelingDate.text= [keyArray objectAtIndex:section];
    feelingDate.frame=CGRectMake(10,-5,tableView.frame.size.width,21);
    feelingDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerView addSubview:feelingDate];
    [feelingDate release];
    return headerView;  
}
```